# How to select one of the options?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, unistd.h

I'm experimenting with POSIX `getopt` function and came across with some issue. I want to provide a mode (either read or write) to the application through  command line arguments. So I tried to do something like this:

```
enum mode{
    read,
    write
};
enum mode mode;

int opt;
while((opt = getopt("rw")) != -1){
    switch(opt){
        case 'w':
            mode = write;
            break;
        case 'r':
            mode = read;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-r-w]\n", argv[0]");
            exit(1);
    }
}
```

The problem is the way it work now it is possible to pass both `-r` and `-w` option which is non-sense. I want the only one of the two modes to be selected.

What is the "idiomatic" way to do so?

Comment: In your case, 1) verify: is "no mode" selected a problem? 2) is optioning the same mode a 2nd time  a problem?

Comment: @chux 1) Yes, I want user to select exactly one mode.

Answer (score 2):

This is so subjective, it's not a great question, but here are some thoughts:

(1) One approach is to have only one option.  Default behavior is read, if the -w option is specified, then mode is write.

(2) Some Unix programs solve the problem by saying "Last argument wins"

(3) Yet another approach is to use separate variables, and detect the condition that both flags were set.

I've seen all three approaches used.  There are probably other ideas out there as well.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I'd probably use something along these lines:

```
enum mode { DEFAULT, READ, WRITE };
enum mode mode = DEFAULT;

int opt;
while ((opt = getopt("rw")) != -1)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
    case 'w':
        if (mode == READ)
            err_exit("cannot use mutually exclusive options -r and -w");
        mode = WRITE;
        break;
    case 'r':
        if (mode == WRITE)
            err_exit("cannot use mutually exclusive options -r and -w");
        mode = READ;
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-r|-w]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
}

if (mode == DEFAULT)
    mode = READ;    // Or write, whichever is your default
```

Note that this avoids using an uninitialized variable `mode`.

I assume a suitable function `err_exit()` which reports an error and exits.  My implementation also has an `err_usage()` which would be used `err_usage("[-r|-w]");` (and uses a function call, `err_setarg0(argv[0])`, to record the program name).  You can find my implementations of those in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

I also avoid using names like `read` and `write` since those are also used for functions and therefore are hidden by the lower-case enumeration constants (they're in the ordinary identifier namespace, the same as functions and variables).  In fact, I'd probably use a prefix such as `OPT_` (hence `OPT_DEFAULT`, `OPT_READ`, `OPT_WRITE`) to avoid collisions with other possible uses of the names.

Comment: If code was `if (mode == READ)` --> `if (mode != DEFAULT)`, then usage like `-w 
-w`,  would be detected.

Comment: Yes, @chux: I actually had `!= DEFAULT` when I started typing, but I decided that the error message would need to be reworked — two tests are necessary to report two different error conditions (both of a pair of mutually exclusive options, versus repeat of an option; I hate sloppy error messages which say "one of a number of conditions is wrong").  On the whole, repeated options setting the same flag are less serious.  A final decision on that depends on context we don't have.  (I'm also assuming that there would actually be more options than just `-r` and `-w` — help, version, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

> How to select one of the options?
>   [I want user to select exactly one mode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577852/how-to-select-one-of-the-options/53578002#comment94019635_53577852)

Create a helper function that tolerates one and only one valid mode.

```
enum mode get_mode(void) {
  int opt = getopt("rw");
  if (opt != -1 && getopt("rw") == -1) {
    switch(opt){
      case 'w': return write;
      case 'r': return read;
    }
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-r-w]\n", argv[0]");
  exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I like how concise this function is, but (as with OP code) this code doesn't call a POSIX compliant getopt.  The argc and argv parameters are missing.  Also, argv will be out of scope inside the function.  Also, read and write will conflict with definitions in the <unistd.h> header file.